# Building application for Application Loader iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to upload my application onto the App Store, however, I'm having a problem at the moment, on iTunes Connect, my application is "Waiting for Upload". I have already Archived and Verified the application, however, I'm not sure what I should choose with the Application Loader as I saw that it accepts .ipa files, but I don't know how to create them.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create this in Xcode presuming you have the correct certificates and provisioning profiles.

1] Ensure Xcode active scheme (drop down selector near top) is set to iOS device - not simulator  -(doesn't need one connected just select that setting).

2] Create an .ipa build. From the menu select Product -> archive.
Xcode will build the app ready for app store release.

3] You will be asked to select which signing credentials you require, select production profile (usually selected for you).

4] You will be asked what type of build. I'm doing this from memory I think it's first option the Ap store submission.

5] If you have already prepared iTunes Connect for this build and the version numbers match it will ask if you would like to upload the build there and then - You do want to do this.

6] Have a glass of wine, your app has been submitted.

Comment: Also check the version numbers match in both the app and on iTunes Connect and double check the number isn't the same as an existing app. This will not work.